# Determining the rotation matrix and subsequent translation which needs to be applied to a plane so that it aligns to an axis plane?

Tags: matrices, geometry, matlab

Hi guys (and girls too),
 This might be the stupidest question to a math versed person but I'm having a lot of trouble and would appreciate it if someone could explain it please:

I would like to determine what angle of rotation I should apply to some plane in 3D whose normal form I have been given (in Matlab those are 4 (a,b,c,d) values representing  a*X+b*Y+c*Z=d) so that after the applied rotation it aligns to an axis plane (i.e. XY plane which should have a normal form written as 1*X+1*Y+0*Z=1 <- unless I'm mistaking this)...

I'm sure it needs to be done using the normalized form thus I should divide the a,b,c values by d first, then try do something with cross product of the planes (as that is dependent on the cos of the angle between such vectors I think) but for the love of everything I am just baffled as to where and how to start with it - especially having seen some explanations using quaternions and similar matrix solutions that seem to be more powerful.

Can anyone help me please? TIA

Comment: Are we rotating around some specific point?

Comment: I've just corrected the question, but since the given plane should align to an axis plane, I would guess not...I'm trying first to understand what needs to be done so that those planes align first (but I'm guessing if and when I try to align some point of the given plane to the origin if those are aligned then the translation should be easier)...my linear algebra is so rusty I'm sure I'm just using so many wrong terms here (please don't mind it since I'm not doing it on purpose)...

Comment: Would it be a simple solution if it were a specific point?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that you should have some specified point with respect to which you are rotating the plane.

Comment: There is an infinite number of such rotations, each corresponding to a rotation axis this lies on the angle bisector of the two plane normals.

Comment: Ok, then this...if choosing origin, to be the point, that rotation will occur around...how can I find a rotation matrix or matrices I should apply to the plane so that after applying them all the plane whose normal I found now sits so that it's parallel (if not aligned with say an XY plane)...I'm thinking I should find the normal of the plane I'm trying to align first, then normalize it and then use the dot product with the vectors (1,0,0), (0,0,1) and (0,0,1) so as to use the arccos of those values and those estimated angles to rotate the plane to be algined after...am I at all close please?